# Set style for custom control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to create a custom user control. I've created ResourceDictionary file (Themes\Generic.xaml) with two styles:

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:my="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wpf/2008/toolkit"
    xmlns:themes="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes;assembly=PresentationFramework.Aero"
    xmlns:components="clr-namespace:ORPO.WPF.Components">

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type components:HeaderFilterDataGrid}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGrid}}">
        ...
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
        ...
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

and my custom control class:

```
public class HeaderFilterDataGrid : DataGrid
    {
...
static HeaderFilterDataGrid()
        {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(HeaderFilterDataGrid),
new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(HeaderFilterDataGrid)));            
        }
...
}
```

It works fine when I apply first style

```
DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(HeaderFilterDataGrid),
    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(HeaderFilterDataGrid)));
```

How can i apply second style for my custom control?
I need both styles to be applied at the same time.

Comment: Try to put the `DataGridColumnHeader` Style in the `Style.Resources` of the `HeaderFilterDataGrid` Style.

Comment: It works! Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the `DataGridColumnHeader` Style in the Resources of the `HeaderFilterDataGrid` Style. This way `DataGridColumnHeader` will be a default style for all DataGridColumnHeaders in a HeaderFilterDataGrid.

```
<ResourceDictionary ...>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type components:HeaderFilterDataGrid}"
           BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGrid}}">
        <Style.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
            ...
            </Style>
        </Style.Resources>
        ...
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```